# If $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is injective, is $V$ finite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler, Section 3.B Question 20 says

> Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. Prove that $T$ is injective iff there exists $S \in \mathcal{L}(W, V)$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on $V$.

It doesn't specify $V$ as being finite-dimensional, and maybe it's not needed for the proof, but I was wondering if it's possible for $V$ to be infinite-dimensional? Also in that section, there is a proposition stating:

> Suppose V and W are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that dim V > dim W. Then no linear map from V to W is injective.

This is specified for finite-dimensional spaces $V$ and $W$. It seems that for infinite-dimensional $V$ this would then definitely be the case, but so why isn't that stated? I was wondering if this is true but maybe proved later in the book or elsewhere, or if it's not true at all.

Comment: Should $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ (not $\mathcal{L}(W, V)$)?

Comment: Thank you @angryavian, yes!

Comment: Sorry, now $T\in L(V,W)$ as well as $S$. They don't compose.

Comment: Ahh thanks, sorry, though at least that's not particularly relevant to the main question, that was just what led me to my question about an injective map from an infinite-dim vector space to finite-dim

Comment: Generally, if $V = N(T) \oplus U$, then $T \colon U \to R(T)$ is an isomorphism. In your case, this means $V$ is isomorphic to $R(T)$, a subspace of $W$, so $\dim V = \dim R(T) \leq \dim W$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The dimension assumptions are not needed for your first question. Here's two steps you can use for proving it below:

> Injective set maps admit left inverses, so a map $f:X\to Y$ (of sets) is injective if and only if there exists $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=id_X$. So the reverse direction of this claim is immediate (even if both $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional).

> If $T:V\to W$ is injective, then fix a basis $\{v_i\}$ for $V$ and notice that $\{T(v_i)\}$ is a linearly independent set in $W$. Now extend this set to a basis for $W$ and define a reverse map $S:W\to V$ by sending all the $T(v_i)$'s to $v_i$ and all the other basis vectors to $0$.

(2) The inequality $\dim(V)>\dim(W)$ in your second question is assuming that these dimensions are *numbers*, so the "fully infinite dimensional" case doesn't apply (in infinite dimensional vector spaces we would have $\dim(V)=\infty=\dim(W)$). But the claim does hold if $\dim(V)=\infty$ and $\dim(W)<\infty$.

Comment: When you say "fix a basis {$v_i$} for V", doesn't that assume $V$ is finite-dimensional? Though my main question was, is it possible to have infinite-dimensional $V$ and an injective map $T:V\rightarrow W$?

Comment: @letslearnmath Bases for vector spaces exist (although I guess this is the axiom of choice), so you can fix a basis for $V$ even if $\dim(V)=\infty$. As per my second point: if $\dim(V)=\infty$ and $\dim(W)<\infty$, then there **does not** exist an injective linear map $V\to W$. If $\dim(V)=\dim(W)=\infty$ then you can have injective linear maps $V\to W$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is the proof to show that there is not an injective linear map a difficult one?

Comment: It's really the same as if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional: basically you just have to pick images for all the basis elements for $V$, but since $V$ has larger dimension than $W$ there has to be some linear dependence amongst the images.

Comment: I see, okay that's easy enough, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are proofs for both cases that don't involve infinite-dimensional bases, now that the question has been edited. They both rely on this: an infinite dimensional vector space has a subspace of arbitrary finite dimension (easy to prove).

1. $T$ cannot be injective unless $V$ is finite dimensional. Restrictions of injective linear maps are injective linear maps, so this would lead to an injective linear map from a finite-dimensional space of dimension greater than $\textrm{dim}\ W$, impossible.
2. I suspect the reason your textbook requires $V$ and $W$ to be finite dimensional is that it hasn't *defined* $\textrm{dim}\ V$ for infinite dimensional $V$. This requires a generalised definition of basis, and cardinal numbers. But anyway, if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, the last proof shows that we cannot have an injective linear map from $V$.